# React Custom Hook Problem - Infinite Dependency Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been loving getting into hooks and dealing with all the new fun issues that come up with real-world problems :) Here's one I've run into a couple of times and would love to see how you "should" solve it!

**Overview:** I have created a custom hook to capsulate some of the business logic of my app and to store some of my state. I use that custom hook inside a component and fire off an event on load.

**The issue is**: my hook's `loadItems` function requires access to my `items` to grab the ID of the last item. Adding `items` to my dependency array causes an infinite loop. Here's a (simplified) example:

**Simple `ItemList` Component**

```js
//
// Simple functional component
//

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import useItems from '/path/to/custom/hooks/useItems'

const ItemList = () => {
    const { items, loadItems } = useItems()

    // On load, use our custom hook to fire off an API call
    // NOTE: This is where the problem lies. Since in our hook (below)
    // we rely on `items` to set some params for our API, when items changes
    // `loadItems` will also change, firing off this `useEffect` call again.. and again :)
    useEffect(() => {
        loadItems()
    }, [loadItems])

    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map(item => <li>{item.text}</li>)}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default ItemList
```

**Custom `useItems` Hook**

```js
//
// Simple custom hook
//

import { useState, useCallback } from 'react'

const useItems = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([])

    // NOTE: Part two of where the problem comes into play. Since I'm using `items`
    // to grab the last item's id, I need to supply that as a dependency to the `loadItems`
    // call per linting (and React docs) instructions. But of course, I'm setting items in
    // this... so every time this is run it will also update.
    const loadItems = useCallback(() => {
        // Grab our last item
        const lastItem = items[items.length - 1]
        // Supply that item's id to our API so we can paginate
        const params = {
            itemsAfter: lastItem ? lastItem.id : nil
        }
        // Now hit our API and update our items
        return Api.fetchItems(params).then(response => setItems(response.data))
    }, [items])

    return { items, loadItems }
}

export default useItems
```

The comments inside the code should point out the problem, but the only solution I can come up with right now to make linters happy is to supply params TO the `loadItems` call (ex. `loadItems({ itemsAfter: ... })`) which, since the data is already in this custom hook, I am really hoping to not have to do everywhere I use the `loadItems` function.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Mike

Comment: on your useEffect, just replace "[loadItems]" to "[]", you just need to fetch on load right? so just once, no more dependency on useEffect.

Comment: Do you want to keep loading items until there are no more items?

Comment: I don't understand how `items` are even being passed into the hook? Where does the hook get `items` from?

Comment: @mattOestreich `loadItems` loads them from the server?

Comment: @JonasWilms I misread the question and OPs code. I thought OP wanted to pass something into the hook, have the hook fetch data, then return that data. Instead, all the hook does is expose a "fetch" function.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to run an effect just once, omit all dependencies:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    loadItems();
 }, []);
```

Comment: [Scroll down to "Question: Why do I sometimes get an infinite refetching loop?"](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#tldr).. Specifically, where Dan states: *'However, removing a dependency you use (or blindly specifying []) is usually the wrong fix.'*.. One thing I have never understood is why so many people recommend doing this, while one of the React authors recommends not supplying an empty array list. (This will also cause a lint error).. Can you elaborate on why this is?

Comment: @mattOestreich I'm not blind. Propose a better solution please :)

Comment: these proposals were written before hooks hit reality.

Comment: This is honestly more of a question than saying you are wrong, as your recommendation would fix this issue - hell, I even use empty dependency arrays when I need to. I just fear that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @mattOestreich Well the dependency array is just there to make sure that all dependencies are refering to the current value ... On the initial render, that *does not matter*, as all the values are guaranteed to be up to date. If you want to reproduce `componentDidMount` always use empty dependencies, and ignore all those other tips.

Comment: Further down in the article Dan explains how empty dependency arrays can bite you, are you saying we do not have to worry about that anymore? Thanks for your input!

Comment: @matt well, it can't bite you *in this case*, and all the solutions provided *don't work here*.

Comment: thank you for your time! I understand that OPs question is not apples to apples with Dan's examples - I see exactly what you mean.  I appreciate it!

Comment: I can’t wait to get back to my computer to reply to some of these :) This one though was my initial solution and technically solves the problem of infinite loop (similar to my way of just passing the needed info in). I guess what I am curious about is “is this the generally recommended way”? There are linters that suggest this behavior should be avoided and as pointed out above there is specific notes in the documentation about not doing this. If this is the only way, so be it, but it seems like since it’s so aggressively recommended that we avoid this... there has to be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

You could try with useReducer, pass the dispatch as loadItems as it never changes reference. The reducer only cares if the action is NONE because that is what the cleanup function of useEffect does to clean up.

If action is not NONE then state will be set to last item of items, that will trigger useEffect to fetch using your api and when that resolves it'll use setItems to set the items.

```
const NONE = {};
const useItems = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [lastItem, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (state, action) => {
      return action === NONE
        ? NONE
        : items[items.length - 1];
    },
    NONE
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    //initial useEffect or after cleanup, do nothing
    if (lastItem === NONE) {
      return;
    }
    const params = {
      itemsAfter: lastItem ? lastItem.id : Nil,
    };
    // Now hit our API and update our items
    Api.fetchItems(params).then(response =>
      setItems(response)
    );
    return () => dispatch(NONE); //clean up
  }, [lastItem]);
  //return dispatch as load items, it'll set lastItem and trigger
  // the useEffect
  return { items, loadItems: dispatch };
};
```